# How Order of the message are being handled in commit log

Tags: apache-kafka

Could you please help me to understand how order are being maintained in commit log in both within partition and across partition?

Comment: When you say "commit log", do you mean segment?

Answer (score 0):

Following pictures will help you:

[image]

[image]

[image]